# ATT Permission Popup Not Showing Without Delay in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, progressive-web-apps

I'm facing an issue with App Tracking Transparency in my iOS app. When I call `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization` immediately in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`, the permission popup doesn't appear. However, it works fine with a delay. Here's my code:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    requestTrackingAuthorization()
    return true
}

private func requestTrackingAuthorization() {
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
            // Handle authorization status
        }
    }
}
```

With the following delay, the popup shows correctly:

```swift
private func requestTrackingAuthorization() {
    let delayInSeconds = 5.0
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delayInSeconds) {
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
                // Handle authorization status
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the permission popup appear without the delay, and how can I implement this without the delay?

Comment: I delayed 2 seconds on my app and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This request requires the application state to be `active`. At the time `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` was executed, its state was `inactive`, before your app's UI had been presented. So that's why it's not showing up. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency/attrackingmanager/requesttrackingauthorization(completionhandler:)?language=objc) here.

> Calls to the API only prompt when the application state is UIApplicationStateActive

You can put `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization` on `viewDidAppear` of any controller, which is the window's root viewController.

Comment: I did try but still not working. https://gist.github.com/sujitpatil72/6e763862fd9a65954c78a7156dd332dc

Comment: I tested it, it doesn't work on viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear. You should put the trigger on viewDidAppear.